# AppBarLayout transparency

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-appbarlayout

I've been playing around with AppBarLayout, but I can't find a way to make it's background transparent.

Here what i mean:

[image]

And here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:text="hey"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="#8000CDFE"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see I am using color #8000CDFE which should give me 50% transparency, but for some reason it doesn't. I've tried setting transparent background to AppBarLayout, but it also doesn't help much.

Has anybody encountered this problem? Is there anyway to assign transparent colors to AppBarLayout and its' siblings?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide us with a more complete xml. Knowing what the parent layout of your views is could be helpful.

Comment: @Ari provided full XML

Comment: I think it IS half transparent.

Comment: @Apurva well, as you can see on a screenshot, it is not :) As  you can see it completely overlays recyclerview.

Comment: @Kistamushken I ran into this problem as well. I was wrapping my `Toolbar` in an `AppBarLayout`, and I wanted them both to be transparent. I could not figure out how to get the `AppBarLayout` to be transparent, so I ended up removing it and just using the `Toolbar`. The `Toolbar` was easy enough to make transparent, just by setting `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`.

Comment: @Bryan yeah, right now I am doing just like this(except I am using TabLayout). But AppBarLayout seems to have pretty cool features that work out of the box, so it will be cool if we find a solution here. I've done some research, and it seems to be a popular concern

Comment: @Kistamushken Do you want the list to be visible underneath the AppBarLayout?

Comment: @Ari yeap, this is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Kistamushken if I put the color code #8000cdfe in any color picker tool, it shows the same color seems in your screenshot

Comment: @Apurva the question is about making it transeparent to contents of the ViewPager and, as you can see on the screenshot it is not the case right now.

Answer (score 6):

**Why it happens:**

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html), `CoordinateLayout` is a special kind of a `FrameaLayout`, so one can assume overlay behavior to work just as it would with a regular `FrameLayout`, right? The thing is, though, that it does things differently when it detects that your RecyclerView has the`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`flag.

When it detects the scrolling beahvior, I am assuming that it does the following (haven't looked at the code, just assuming): 
   It places the `RecyclerView` just below `AppBarLayout`, but retains its full height. When scrolling occurs, all it does is set the `RecyclerView`'s translationY to negative numbers to move it up by the scroll value.

**Possible solution:**

1. Set translation of `RecyclerView` to -appBarHeight.
   This will make it appear underneath the appBar.
2. Increase the `RecyclerView`'s height by appBarHeight. This is to offset the translationY changes caused by the scrollBehavior.

For example, here is how you can do it:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
            mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }

        recyclerView.setTranslationY(-appBarHeight);
        recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = recyclerView.getHeight()+appBarHeight;
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds legit, will try soon and let you know about results, thanks.

Comment: `it does things differently when it detects that your RecyclerView has theapp:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behaviorflag`
This helped me find my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These simple few lines of code would do the trick

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
AppBarLayout barLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);    

mRecyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                mRecyclerView.setTranslationY(-barLayout.getHeight());
                mRecyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = mRecyclerView.getHeight()+barLayout.getHeight();
            }
        });
```